# Tween.js | My tween isn't updating even when I loop it

Tags: javascript, object, tweenjs

So, I'm creating a game in which I have a ship with a gun that shoots bullets.

I want the gun of the ship to bounce back when I shoot so it looks like the gun actually shot the bullet. Everything is fine so far, the gun is only moving relative to the body, and nothing's been stuck in infinite loops so far.

My ship is made from a constructor I coded that works perfectly, so to create the tweens, instead of making variables inside the constructor that I can't reuse, I made the tweens actual attributes of the object.

This is what the code looks like:

```
this.gunTweenPosition = {y : unit / -1.52 + (gunLength * unit / -4)};
this.gunTweenTarget = {y : av.gunTweenPosition.y + unit / 6};
this.gunTween1 = new TWEEN.Tween(av.gunTweenPosition.y).to(av.gunTweenTarget.y, 1000);
this.gunTween2 = new TWEEN.Tween(av.gunTweenTarget.y).to(av.gunTweenPosition.y, 1000);
this.gunTween1.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.In);
this.gunTween2.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out);
this.gunTween1.onUpdate(function() {
  this.gun.position.y = av.gunTweenPosition.y;
});
this.gunTween2.onUpdate(function() {
  this.gun.position.y = av.gunTweenTarget.y;
});
```

'this' being the object we're constructing,
and to start the function that will push and pull the gun, I have this function that I just call:

```
car avatar = this;
var number = 0;
function loopTweenUpdating() {
  number++;
  if (number < 20) {
    avatar.gunTween1.update();
    avatar.gunTween1.onComplete(function() {
      avatar.gunTween2.update();
    });
    setTimeout(loopTweenUpdating, 20);
  }
}
```

I can't see what the problem is here.

Click [THIS](http://gamingjs.com/ice/#B/3Rtrd9M49ju/QsuHwS6J46SkFCg9pw0FZhd2OG13gP3CcR018TSxMraTNnDy3/fqLUtympQOy25P29jSfcj3pXuvnIMLMlwePjj4W7uNOh00mJASo5MFLpbVOMtH6BsdbbcBokyLbFahskhfPhxX1ex5pzNKpgDz97MoJdPO+bjAOPqjfHh40OGwGyDNxssy2xZpMC7IFL/ObnC5Ler5Ncb5tkjvybxseLLDByCeM1xVAF0yYT1A6AN9qD/KiIOUUTKdEvQSPfLRpnNA+tELD941Ka5w0YQ549BfOJSksUgKVKY4x4CW42tF84yOBd/QJUhteJ5N8VmFZ89RD3XQXoxWIcVleFGJqzdFssiqZUAJnL89PTmJfsdpRYrdIG4h+huGktd1NqzGwOs6y4fkOsryHBcf6VgLAOjPGGejcWVBvGWDEmSeZxyAktqRGB3UexrHMWWUXaLAmj1A3Zj9hI3o3Wfr0Pu3YXfXYff667H39jgyFVGaTHGRCH1wcf5WVGMyKpLZOEsHbDpgsmgzQp1eC6kLTpJetfVlt8UfH5CYJjiLaEbKrMpITnUo1gxSbBkS5XiGtpPhMODYSqUFzoe4YIanV/wRX7x5dypmAgYr4Si3s+wrDlwb8CidoQ5JOp/ivIpo9ImS2QxIDcbZZBgookMyPZlgCgQY4GQr6lvwebRIKljkgORlVcypVUq3u5znKX16ARJQ2gMyIUUL0cvTZJjNS34tVjea5wIArt7hfCQGxfSULPDZDONhC5VjQipxfTGfTHA1SGZJCk4i76kE5PWrZJqM1N1bnEwouYQtS95N8AJPQvSN6R1ibclkYXktPOUC37zH5TgQvqI1ck6KefkGQySsimXADBGsNnoGZmg+rpjYE8Pi0frgxXtxKD1Q8ksLnFT4PfwVWTKRPE2udC3HSZmlCuhbSkX4HClxr0KIEFEfTE3gh+yTKd54VL+1dqNdw17ZnXwCQUDbrSLlkAaKR/loPkmK1wk1kcZI1g19uO+yHK9B7TIHjGuoyoBAg+raJp3kowk+J8c0OMd8skah5nF+rQ/mF9hWei/qg3a13cphPijtun+v2paus4GyAbSu61gtsd2N+j30GAVafDtq7gkl7ahHKR5QQluGFWxsIMR+bGIxJyzPxqTSYmczyr9hXF0b89rpAUDfOLRlKACo+oADSYOEgqI3DgQLHYkG4qHEAeNRREHxWwPqEoYVjBl4DJh0XkC01aQsRFu2WfmvGUBdJpPSXE9WviLXuXfiHb6svBOnIiWwZ9IkZzwgsFvDgoc7IXi4E5KHO3M+L+q02D+68yULIQY+niyokbGU8YOwX5j/tkTPN7TflUPnPClGuJJUPAyiJZCTEc/F78oQ8fHk5J8RGwq8VMKoIoHDOFoaCUCNcG89YYluk9UMmwh3IwwBJB8FnPIJu6FhLEujX3PPQtbA/zavfAwIWM0QAlQgM4BA7qsSUMefJfMHz/o53ZVvQd9BX8qtTt0IWGCL54QVGEFohSY+sII/ntBEs4JUpFrOsIlG3cheFk1ZTWvXy+VxbUaqT9Lh61vxzQsb8LMfcNkMyG92wDnAlPlWXgN2tkLYXMYRPGHeCyAmlaT4hNrGSluIj342Rz+HLs0vX4ZZUS1PSZUIX9U+7oEzfNqBozrdgJwBto4a41oIOnILhF+POMRjrYyYxPJdMy4BAVrBkXmlLBJR3XNQy6ZWMvFkmyM3qRc+m6Im5zMmHrPzMhviI0gYpJkqG2P7wi+/GBE89BpMgx3R6CniXR8Kqh1ra3aYsZ3AYEfv78qwvRFHtsUYHOm9l+NNg09tzZHvXQZLNnBXns0sPUnv73hC0g1q/7sapwhsq5ZO2NbY5CQrK5y/JgXkmnANtMpGE4XE8GQB+cw7hgNF6qNUIj1qaZwLeL4rHRCp1NkQFTu5INUxS6g0AEJ8epiVtE5NikBFnnV5VH2wLYkY2Zx08voauAh+wCJogVBfyGqNIrT/++RPTaHJEFtqnU0Oqc3/Bh3y3GeHVn5hc5LHgQ/WARu5pYTmNWbbi+Wmi3JBm2BZzJbATNSwfjwry+U4hxvgOIz8AnPSZbmqNcCKtN8CWP1jKt9te7CC0LSJfD69YH0kUXWpgDAhZMbyI5ZY0WxP2zpHevz4heEdgtAB6sWmU4iYojPBOc/TDOdwQAjUrdMZrNabznlQeh6qK+PaCHjOY7Xogi0vWxc86bMK9lZpeYhq46yc1cum5PjErQ0ks7w/m41x4bQTWKvIUK4chgy/Bw8Uao++rZGwYeNIG4/qJsTRvqISys6CFCRHqPcUpHScXVBYfKC1qgq1ONrtAwQwpB81+bJCvYP26c7J0tOUlDUeOn99zAE+/Mr8qh+qfMvNO+5pLVARbbwWbX66b8bJ2uIc19sFkdtZUKBiB7FAX9U2NwGaTLKFAckaNB0ke+smTbm1GTGGJQ583QVmmYNc+srChjB2Nr+oiiStrARcAFwQoMkaOV1rpr7n+rE3SY+EcsWDGr2jO1jQbbS2swBb01t1R1GDJDbtjiJfsLeNxE7dHqrU7WFz6mbrVm8Zlk23284Et2BzgiVhdVs59LlCfa8wsAwTrMMgT+g2OetEsNGgjW1fOLPedGz/adVdb8fsy5jM9B7mLk+KcsXTAeP4heXIa09fGMT3H77QKvYeD18Kuqq/+uyl5z97efLfPHuRbGL2udkhjHVkKB8Dwsn//BGMqPLc/u93nsF0/Wcw3CYMA+/9jKcwcfR0D6oOTxN7XwHt/5UnMcrZqV7k9f/hSYwRhb7nIOYuByv+Uw8lfd1sZv5h9Zrv0GQu7B6z6n9+vVPn9vaOrNWyC328rd4rW+Rj2wZZfhp6yDptuLV02+vo6jKwkPHo1hYag5TaWok9zWqh2dpLqipJr7as290lUSFwdk5dag57ylJYyb+l5TcZwr2Wr7ssEnsK2N2fuoBVe6/q3O4IoflLCSZXO9sPFZKO5XQT2uubO/oGHGiBsTWHO9SapvGsLzVNyLWVpvaKn67QNBrMjXXmj6zMtq9ut7ZIVctubWm+lf60haJrx3epE51Q+lOVic7qmqtEpiQktaRejFWv/bl6vMLLIbmuaRFTCHNbSsmQOjgbjwBhAPd8BZ3OfNZClAAt7i4r2BtpsFNbF8d8+RLt7oey3BXvs9R75ArwSWwAetvpmuZTA9R7VKFBnxmg7pFDp5PAU7hoe/1QSP82Bnv7GtJ/pKHX0pOgPEeo7e9844xvYmkUq/p7m14Fzmc/Xn3Wgcha/TXB+hTYCOvToAG8hQqbWPh0qA9n1Gu64lUJ9XbELfqZ0vcB6NbWqCMkSSolzSD0fXpRm/xcm/wsl2T4/oDlUugISprEaQ5Nkyt8TIohrOimhZYtdA2JiWkkF2zSSgOPSUMfplaJU1It9Kx/v62V+GaX/WzYWeHrr6d2/Eljp3nCYeuIWXksJSD9duUIkHrrV4/seKZ/V8ndu+Cesh8quO6tYoOlb9SL+upKEVBDR05Jnk3ZoZ2QT4H/nOMSsis6DACvi2SKAwElaKp3z/lFwHi0kPF6fI3FKOHfolA8xPcnsikkcPq80NiDJQZ/V66zJ0Kr6T3vj/5xggZvj06PBucnp2fSgWrnhVT64h13HqHjmIu4paxV3veoxbJ/XfNXv+svKj1Kkjdu707RjAHJZIJeC0Gp7V98GYDk6SSr1aTmCyIsQwycAzC5GdHtiOXkRiSJ3XalHAkt0GvendsK3DRC8cUMjrUGOm4ApJ7b7vb6atrgq0yW3mjj0oI1vn0kvq61Ut/O6rDvcf0H) link to see the full code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing to start the tween.

```
this.gunTween1.start();
```